# Regex to match all repeating alphanumerical subpatterns

Tags: python, regex

After searching for a while, I could only find how to match *specific* subpattern repetitions. Is there a way I can find (3 or more) repetitions for *any* subpattern ?

For example:

```
re.findall(<the_regex>, 'aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_')
→ ['a', 'b', 'x', 'aaabbbxxx_']

re.findall(<the_regex>, 'lalala luuluuluul')
→ ['la', 'luu', 'uul']
```

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate and would be grateful to be redirected to the original question.

Comment: Would it be possible to get only the first match instead? I'm editing the question to reflect this case.

Comment: Your final example suggests that you are looking for potentially overlapping patterns. This is significant enough that you should probably [edit] the question to clarify this. The examples help, but I really think some overall clarification would also be useful or even necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this lookahead based regex you may not get exactly as you are showing in question but will get very close.

```
r'(?=(.+)\1\1)'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJpwss/2)

**Code:**

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?=(.+)\1\1)')
>>> reg.findall('aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_')
['aaabbbxxx_', 'b', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'x']
>>> reg.findall('lalala luuluuluul')
['la', 'luu', 'uul']
```

**RegEx Details:**

Since we're using a lookahead as full regex we are not really consuming character since lookahead is a zero width match. This allows us to return overlapping matches from input.

Using `findall` we only return capture group in our regex.

- `(?=`: Start lookahead

  - `(.+)`: Match 1 or more of any character (greedy) and capture in group #1
  - `\1\1`: Match 2 occurrence of group #1 using back-reference `\1\1`
- `)`: End lookahead

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall()` won't find overlapping matches. But you can find the non-overlapping matches using a capture group followed by a positive lookahead that matches a back-reference to that group.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = r'(.+)(?=\1{2})'
>>> re.findall(regex, 'aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_')
['aaabbbxxx_', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'x']
>>> re.findall(regex, 'lalala luuluuluul')
['la', 'luu']
>>>
```

This will find the longest matches; if you change `(.+)` to `(.+?)` you'll get the shortest matches at each point.

```
>>> regex = r'(.+?)(?=\1{2})'
>>> re.findall(regex, 'aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_')
['a', 'b', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'x']
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without defining the *subpattern* first.

Anyway, if the subpattern is just <any_alphanumeric>, then `re.findall(<the_regex>, 'aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_aaabbbxxx_')` would produce something like this :

`['a', 'b', 'x', 'aa', 'ab', 'bb', 'bx', 'xx', 'x_', 'aaa', 'aaab', 'aaabb', ....]`

ie, every alphanumeric combination that is repeated thrice - so a lot of combinations, not just `['a', 'b', 'x', 'aaabbbxxx_']`